# Adjust CSS/html of a form element in DJango

Tags: html, css, django, forms

Been trying to teach myself some CSS while working in django and have hit a wall.  I'm working as part of a team. I have been using the following form to submit data (which works fine), but have been unable to change the CSS of the form element (particularly text boxes)

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  {{ form.description.errors }}
  <label for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}"></label>
  {{ form.description }}
</div>
```

Given the above code, I believe that the element I need to manipulate, and that which controls the textbox on my screen is {{ form.description }}.  But I can't seem to figure out how to apply any changes to it, at least from the template page.

I've seen this done in tutorials using the input tag, and I've seen people using widgets to edit the attributes, but I don't want to change the configuration too much, and my implementation of a widget didnn't work.

Is this possible, or do I need to dig into the code and edit the forms class that controls this?

Thanks

Comment: You said you had tried adjusting the widget for the field. What did you try? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from the django form class.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}))
```

If say it's a modelform and you are not manually instantiating fields, you can override `__init__` as usual and modify

```
self.fields['my_field'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'my-class'
```

You can always manually construct the HTML too instead of relying on form field auto rendering, just as you've done with the label.